# Itext tamil font is not displayed correctly

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

When generating a PDF using IText the tamil font (one of the indian language) is not displayed properly. But when I copy the text in PDF and past it in text editor it is displaying correctly. I am trying this in ubuntu 14.X LTS.

Here are the screenshots with actual and expected output:

Incorrect display:

[image: Incorrect display]

Correct display:

[image: correct display]

I have used the following line of code to create the font.

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("/home/user/Downloads/lohit-tamil-ttf-2.91.1/Lohit-Tamil.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font myfont1 = new Font(bf, 15, Font.NORMAL);

document.open();
document.add(new Paragraph(    "படிகஅமைப்பு முகவரி."  , myfont1));
document.add(new Paragraph(    "\u0ba4\u0bae\u0bbf\u0bb4\u0bcd\u0ba8\u0bbe\u0b9f\u0bc1" , myfont1));
```

Comment: All versions up to iText 5.5.8 don't support the ligatures needed for Tamil. The next version of iText will support Tamil, but it is only available in beta for a selected number of test users. [Contact iText for more info.](http://itextpdf.com/contact) If you don't want to contact iText, the answer is simple: you're trying to do something that isn't possible with the public versions of iText.

Comment: Hi Bruno Lowagie, Thanks for the info

Comment: The "next version" @Bruno talked about is itext 7.x when also using the separate calligraphy module.